# Why does '+' operator for sequences hang?

Tags: kotlin, sieve-of-eratosthenes

The following is a minimal reproducible example of an application with two attempts at an unbounded Eratosthenes Sieve:

```
interface SieveImplementation {
    fun sieve(seq: Sequence<Int>): Sequence<Int>
}

object Attempt1 : SieveImplementation {
    override fun sieve(seq: Sequence<Int>): Sequence<Int> = sequence {
        yield(seq.first())
        yieldAll(sieve(seq.drop(1).filter { it % seq.first() != 0 }))
    }
}

object Attempt2 : SieveImplementation {
    override fun sieve(seq: Sequence<Int>): Sequence<Int> =
        sequenceOf(seq.first()) + sieve(seq.drop(1).filter { it % seq.first() != 0 })
}

fun primes(attempt: SieveImplementation): Sequence<Int> {
    return attempt.sieve(generateSequence(2) { it + 1})
}

fun main() {
    primes(Attempt1).take(5).forEach(::println)  // Works OK
    primes(Attempt2).take(5).forEach(::println)  // Hangs
}
```

Why does Attempt1 work just fine, but Attempt2 hangs forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Attempt2, `sieve` calls itself before returning, which calls itself before returning, which calls itself before returning, and so on in an infinite loop. Thus, it can never return and will eventually crash with a `StackOverflowError`.

The reason why Attempt1 (seemingly) works is because it's implemented as a coroutine, i.e. the code pauses execution at each `yield` until the next value is requested. That too will eventually crash with a `StackOverflowError` if you iterate it for too long; it's just less obvious due to the incremental evaluation.

Comment: Thanks, you're _nearly_ right: Attempt2 has been running solidly for 30 minutes now, without crashing with StackOverflowError. Perhaps the compiler realises that the function can be optimized into an iterative form (even without `tailrec`). But I understand the reason it hangs, thanks to your explanation.

Comment: @k314159 Also, I just noticed another thing that may or may not be relevant. Sequences aren't guaranteed to be iterable more than once; in fact, the documentation of `generateSequence` explicitly states that it is _not_ supported for the returned value. Each call to `first()` on the sequence _should_ count as an iteration of the sequence, so I'm surprised it doesn't immediately start throwing `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @BambooleanLogic, that's only true for some specific Sequence implementations. A sequence built using `+` with two sequences doesn't have this constraint (it's not mentioned in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/plus.html)). So that's the reason it's not throwing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, except the concatenation sequence is basically just a wrapper around the two input sequences, including one that should already have been indirectly iterated over at least once. Turns out, the reason it doesn't throw is because I misread the documentation. It's `generateSequence(next)` that's restricted to a single iteration, not `generateSequence(seed, next)`, which is what's used in the code above.